# How to check if a number has subscript in it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

I have a string which is like: `t = '²'`

This throws my code off: `int(t)` with the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '²'
```

How do I detect if a string is a superscript and not a real integer?

I just want to cast a string number to int and get the integer. I want to make sure that the numbers I pass doesn't throw the above error.

I don't want to use `try/except` block.

Comment: If you really don't want to use `try/except`, then you can use a regular expression to match against `r"\d*"`.

Comment: Interestingly, in Python-2.7 `"²".isdigit()` used to return False.  I wonder why that was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is_digit` method returns `True` for subscripts and superscripts. You can use a combination of `int` and `is_digit` to implement that:

```py
def is_subscript(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        try:
            int(s)
        except ValueError:
            return True
    return False
```

Then

```py
print(is_subscript('²'))   # Should print True
print(is_subscript('2'))   # Should print False
```

Comment: Thanks, .isnumeric() returns True too. I don't want to use try except block and want to check the string beforehand without explicit casting.

Comment: In that case you may use a regex, e.g. `re.match("\d+$", s)` but that won't catch decimals and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the string like this

```
SUP = str.maketrans("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹","0123456789")
t = '²'
print(int(t.translate(SUP)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isdecimal()` for testing. Unlike `.isnumeric()` and `.isdigit()`, it does not recognize '²', etc. as a digit:

```
"²".isdecimal()
# False
"2".isdecimal()
#True
```